# Should you FIT train, test or all x and y values for a LinearRegression?

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, model, regression

I have seen so many examples for LinearRegression and all so different. The question is should I fit train, test or all data to the model? Any example had a different way of handling the regression...

This is the split of data, no problem here:

```
X = data[['day']].values
y = data[['ozone']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)
```

But when I fit the model, what option should I choose?

```
model = LinearRegression()
```

```
1. model.fit(X_train,y_train)
2. model.fit(X_test,y_test)
3. model.fit(data[['day']].values, data[['ozone']].values) #X and y
```

Also, I must say that the offered plots show the best results using the third method. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Did you figure things out? I just noticed you never really mentioned the size of your dataset, that would be helpful info for what size split you should make.

Answer (score 2):

The reason so many examples out there are so different is because context trumps method. For example, if I'm running a physics experiment to verify a theoretical equation, then in essence the theoretical equation itself is the "test set" and I would want to use as much data as I could (i.e. use all the data) to reduce bias and variance in the estimate. So, if your ozone problem is very well supported by theoretical physical reasoning and you just want to solve for some coefficients (i.e. physical constants) then you want to use the entire dataset to nail down those coefficients as best as possible. In the statistical sense, the physical motivation acts as a "prior," and can be extremely well known (for more about this viewpoint I suggest Kruschke's Bayesian Analysis book).

On the other hand, if you have no idea what sort of effects could be driving the ozone measurements you're getting, and you want to solve for an unknown mapping (using a linear basis set that you assume will work to describe that mapping) then you should hold out some level of your actual measurements to see how well that mapping can generalize.

Lots of "machine learning" these days is primarily data driven because we're coming to the point where we have loads of accessible data, and as such when you take courses that describe methods of data fitting and descriptors (e.g. linear regression) they often come from the entirely data driven context. Whether physically driven or data driven, the methods are very similar and the way you use the methods can even blend together in the middle of either extreme.

More to your question and how to code it, if you take the data driven approach of dividing a train and test set then what you are really doing is saying you want to fit your model to some random sample of "training data" but since you have nothing to compare to later you need to see how well that fit generalizes to some more data, the "test data." So fit your "train data" and then predict or evaluate on your "test data" to see how well your model or mapping works on "unseen" data.
E.g. (expanding on your code)

```
X = data[['day']].values
y = data[['ozone']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(3), LinearRegression())  # If you think 3rd order poly basis ought to work
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

You fit your model on the `train` sets, so the features `X_train` and the target `y_train`. So in your case, it is option 1:

```
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Once your model is trained, you can test your model on the `X_test`, and comparing the `y_pred` that results from running the model on the test set to the `y_test`.

The reason you get the 'best plots' for your metric while using option 3 is that you are essentially training on the **whole dataset**. If you then test on a subset of that, then naturally you will get a better score, as you then test your model on the data it had seen during training. You should never do that.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is: train your model on the train sample.

Whatever your model is (linear regression or anything else), you always want to make sure your model is not **over-fitted**, meaning it will still perform well for unseen data. That's why you should always train your model on a subset of the full dataset (the training dataset), and use the testing set to assess the model performances (R2 or the metrics best suited for your application).

So you should:

```
X = data[['day']].values
y = data[['ozone']].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

And then:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

From there you can compare `y_pred` to `y_test`.